# Neo4j: Relationship was encountered that had startNode: -1 and endNode: -1

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

When we're querying our neo4j database with queries which touch every node in the graph we're getting the following error:

```
neo4j.exceptions.DatabaseError: While loading relationships for Node[(0-9)*] 
a Relationship[(0-9)*] was encountered that had startNode: -1 and endNode: -1, 
i.e. which had neither start nor end node as the node we're loading relationships for
```

The number/index of the node and relationship is always the same.

One example of a failing query is the one which is executed when you're clicking on a property in the `property keys` section of the neo4j browser:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE EXISTS(n.[property]) RETURN DISTINCT "node" 
as entity, n.[property] AS [property] LIMIT 25 
UNION ALL 
MATCH ()-[r]-() WHERE EXISTS(r.[property]) RETURN DISTINCT "relationship" 
AS entity, r.[property] AS [property] LIMIT 25
```

Basically it's the same problem as in [Neo4j node/relation inconsistencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739860/neo4j-node-relation-inconsistencies) but the query

```
MATCH ()-[r]->()
WHERE ID(r) = (0-9)*
RETURN r;
```

doesn't throw an error as opposed to their problem. We're just getting an empty result and the consistency checker doesn't find any inconsistencies.

When trying to find the problem with something like

```
MATCH (n1)-[*]->(n2), (n1)<-[*]-(n3)
WHERE ID(n1) = 156827743
RETURN n1, n2, n3;
```

we're running into the error again.

Is this a problem with our data or did we miss something else?

Answer (score 0):

We realised that copying the data with `rsync` caused the error. With `scp` it's just fine.